# Why some numbers are added to url of ajax object and how to remove them?

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-string

I Wanna download file for further use, this is the best way I've found, but when I see the Log that is created by `beforeSend` Event, the URL has been modified by a queryString like:

```
http://blabla.com/test.swf?_=1346484617818
```

Numbers are random too.

I wonder why this happens !!!!

```
var url = 'http://blabla.com/test.swf';

$(document).ready(function () {
           $.ajaxSetup({
             'beforeSend':function () {
                          console.log(this.url);}
           });

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType:"script",
            });
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just use cache : true. jQuery will automatically add a timestamp to the end of the URL for you, making sure that ajax requests are never cached.

**from jquery docs**

> **Default:** true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>   If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. 
>   Setting cache to `false` also appends a query string parameter,
>   "`_=[TIMESTAMP]`",  to the URL.

```
$.ajaxSetup({'cache':true});
```

[Jquery Ajax Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: You're on the right way but in the wrong direction ;) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: For datatypes _script_ and _jsonp_ jQuery uses `cache: false` as default and will therefor add `_=[TIMESTAMP]` to prevent caching. To prevent this, you will have to use `cache: true`.

Comment: Thanks for the information @rahul , helped me a lot, but when I used your code the time stamp was still there.
I used the `true` value, and it didn't add the time stamp.

Comment: This is the Final Answer as the result of comments
`$.ajaxSetup({'cache':true});`

Comment: dataType has a lot to do with the default behavior too.  cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue too and I discovered that the problem was from the url. Instead of using http, you should use https. So here's what I mean,
instead of this:

```
var url = 'http://blabla.com/test.swf';
```

use this:

```
var url = 'https://blabla.com/test.swf';
```

I'd like to note that my case was using IIS server for localhost (asp.net, knockout and JQuery Ajax).

Comment: I think you might not got the point. The problem was with those random numbers which were created in order to prevent loading cached content. So changing the protocol has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @AtaIravani Noted