# jQuery getScript function adds search parameter and a 404 error is thrown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use [`getScript()` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to import Bootstrap 3 js file:

```
$.getScript("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js");
```

I cannot understand why jQuery adds a search parameter to the url and the result is a 404 - Not found error:

```
GET http://netdna[...]/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1379832218975 404 (Not Found) 
// Why does this parameter appear? -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I created a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zBjca/) that demonstrates this.

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why some numbers are added to url of ajax object and how to remove them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225576/why-some-numbers-are-added-to-url-of-ajax-object-and-how-to-remove-them)

Comment: Straight from the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) appends a query string for ajax calls, to prevent caching, with the current unix timestamp. By default, [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) will set this flag.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

See [`jQuery.ajax` settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: `$.getScript()` sets `cache:false` by default, you can check that in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests).

Comment: Sorry, I had to post a simple answer first, because you guys are just way too fast for me, and I was like... "ooooh I know this."

Comment: Yeah no worries. @Rikard seeing as it is the exact same solution as in the linked dupe question and in the [`$.getScript` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests) linked earlier, I'd be astonished if it didn't work. Well, changing topics a bit, it is slightly astonishing already that a CDN will fail to load a resource just because of a query string parameter, guess it has something to do with their back-end routing.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It would be micro-optimization at it's finest.

Comment: @Shea talking about their back-end or related to the answer? I've edited out a couple misleading parts from your answer (implying that OP had `cache:false` somewhere) because in fact `$.getScript` is the culprit (link to docs in my first comment).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I was just thinking, for a server whose sole purpose is to serve some specific files, why would the HTTP server need to waste microseconds, to process query strings? One thing I am certain of though, is that the CDN is looking for a file named "bootstrap.min.js?_=1379832218975" and not "bootstrap.min.js".

Comment: Yeah I thought the same. `=]`