# Extra ?= and numbers in GET request header when called through AJAX

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, scrapy

I'm trying to a scrape using Python a certain type of website ([this one](https://www.buzzpoker.com/buzz-odds) for example) that uses`AJAX` requests with `jquery` to load some of it's content (I'm also aware of the very good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax), but at the moment I think Selenium might be unnecessary for my problem).

I can see using Firebug that when I load a menu cookies get set in a logical way, which use numbering system to group events like:

```
(Sport, Country, Competition, Event)
```

e.g. for all Soccer, England events the numbers are

```
(7, 55,0,0)
```

Then when the javacript function `updateCenter()` is called, it uses this set of cookies to build a URL based on these cookie values, like:

```
 var loadUrl = "/_betting/getCenterColumn/" + centerStateCookie + "/" + selectedSport
 + "&" + selectedCategory + "&" + selectedCompetition + "&" + selectedEvent + "&" + 
 selectedLiveNowEvent + "&" + expandBetNbrInActiveSettledBets;
```

For my example above this looks like:

```
/_betting/getCenterColumn/displayEventsFromCategory/7&55&0&0&0&0
```

Finally an `AJAX` request is made to update the center DIV with content loaded from that URL:
(the `.html(ajax_load)` initial call just loads a nice whirly timer gif in the meantime while request is processed):

```
$("#PluginBettingCenterContent").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
```

All well and good, but the Firebug XHR requests actually show that the GET link requested wasn't quite the above but has some numbers appended:

```
 GET /_betting/getCenterColumn/displayEventsFromCategory/7&55&0&0&0&0?_=1392198690842
```

Where does this `?_=1392198690842` come from in such an `AJAX` request?

Since I can easy scrape and build the URL that goes into the `AJAX` load, I was hoping just to scrape these URLs directly, but I don't understand what the final set of numbers and `?_=` appended to this URL GET request are, and how I could simulate computing them....

Comment: it's an epoch timestamp and it's appended to prevent caching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225576/why-some-numbers-are-added-to-url-of-ajax-object-and-how-to-remove-them

Comment: @DavidFregoli Oh, you mean so that the newest odds are always loaded rather than some old page a client may have sitting there from a previous call? I should be able to simulate this timestamp from my python code then. I can't see exactly where in the `betting.js` on the site, this timestamp gets appended to the ajax call though. Does it happen internally in `jquery`?

Comment: yes it's an internal thing, see the linked url (it can be disabled). Browsers cache servers' response based on the url string so this is basically a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely the timestamp parameter in the URL is optional.

However, if you want to act as close as the browser, you can append the timestamp manually:

```
>>> import time
>>> url = 'http://example.com/index'
>>> '%s?_=%d' % (url, time.time() * 1000)
'http://example.com/index?_=1392249064418'
```