# DUPLICATE: $.ajax appending request url

Tags: php, ajax, json

[Why does jQuery.ajax() add a parameter to the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749560/why-does-jquery-ajax-add-a-parameter-to-the-url)

Cache needs to be true.

Any suggestions as why this will not work? It won;t print the console.logs showing that this wont even allow me in. This call is appending my request URL with &_=1396146406542. How do I get rid of that add-on? So the request URL is

chatlist.php?PHPSESSID=a8f2b228d783642848da94699ce85c03&_=1396146406542

and I just want it to be

chatlist.php?PHPSESSID=a8f2b228d783642848da94699ce85c03&

$.ajax({

```
url: "chatlist.php?PHPSESSID=a8f2b228d783642848da94699ce85c03",
cache: false,
success: function(data){
  window.console && console.log("JSON Received"); //wont print
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492838/why-does-getjson-silently-fail

Comment: Sorry I changed it up.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225576/why-some-numbers-are-added-to-url-of-ajax-object-and-how-to-remove-them?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of cache: false. It adds the timestamp to avoid caching

[jquery.ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
Type: Boolean
If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Set it to:

```
url: "chatlist.php?PHPSESSID=a8f2b228d783642848da94699ce85c03",
cache: true <--
```