# :1 appended to cross-domain jQuery AJAX call with JSONP: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, cross-domain

I'm trying to call a webservice from website othersite.com on example.com.

Code on othersite.com:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/api/searchcityandcountry/?q=" + cityval + '&cid=1',
    data: "",
    cache:true,
    dataType: "jsonp",//used to be json
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

But when this call is made I see the following error in my dev console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Looking at the actual call it has become:
        http://www.example.com/api/searchcityandcountry/?q=bost&cid=1&callback=callback:1

If I enter that URL in my browser address bar directly, the correct response is given.
Also if I look at the Network tab I see this request `?q=bost&cid=1&callback=callback` (so no `:1`) which returns a HTTP status code of 200 
Why is that `:1` appended and how can I remove it to have this cross-domain call work?

My WCF webservice signature:

```
      <OperationContract()> _
<Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, _
UriTemplate:="searchcityandcountry/?q={q}&cid={cid}")> _
        Function searchCityAndCountry(ByVal q As String, ByVal cid As Integer) As Stream
```

I based this code on what I found here:

- [JSONP call showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)
- [Why some numbers are added to url of ajax object and how to remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225576/why-some-numbers-are-added-to-url-of-ajax-object-and-how-to-remove-them)
- [:1 is being appended to my ajax requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255270/1-is-being-appended-to-my-ajax-requests-with-jquery)